# React make messages of other user appear different color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, django

I am making a chat app with django channels and react and I want messages from a different user to appear at a different color.

To create the messages I save them in state

```
const [messages,setMessages] = useState([])
chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
     if (ran == true) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        setMessages(old => [...old, <p ref={oneRef} className={currentUser[0]?.username}>{data.message}</p>])
                
      }
 }

function theone(e) {

        
        e.preventDefault()
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': myInput
        })); 
        
        setMyInput2('')

<form onSubmit={theone} className="myForm">
       <input onChange={isChanging} placeholder="Message..." type="text" value={myInput} />
 </form>
```

For every message's className  it is the current user's username. I want to basically do something like this.

```
{currentUser.username} {
    background:'red'
}
```

And if not then appear a different color.

How can I make it work.

Comment: Shouldn't the chatSocket message response should have the sender information? Share your response packet.

Comment: @rachitiir you mean the consumers?

Comment: Say you have 3 users X, Y and Z. If X and Y sent message, then Z's chatSocket will receive both messages over chatSocket. Share the schema of your e.data variable above.

Comment: ``e.data`` just contains the message.

Comment: Share more code about your component rendering the messages and when the current user sends the message.

Comment: I edited the form

Answer (score 1):

You should include the sender while sending the message to chatSocket. Ideally, this should be injected by the backend otherwise your api can be exploited. But this looks like a playgroup app, so here's the simple solution.

```
chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
    'message': myInput,
    'sentBy': currentUser //assuming currentUser is a string describing username of current user
  }));
```

Then in `onmessage`, use

```
setMessages(old => [...old, data])
```

and finally render the `messages` as follows -

```
messages.map(({message, sentBy}, idx) => (
    <p key={idx} className={sentBy === currentUser ? 'currentUser' : 'otherUser'}> 
      {message}
    </p>
  ))
```

Use css to differentiate the messages -

```
 .currentUser {
  background: 'red';
 }

 
 .otherUser {
  background: 'yellow';
 }
```

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting answers if they helped :)